# File-Loader not reading Image files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-file-loader, file-loader

I am getting an issue where the file-loader does not read any image files. I tried adding png to file-loader in webpack.base.config to no avail. It doesn't read any format either. Also tried updated file-loader version, didn't fix it.

EDIT: Added webpack code below. I am using webpack version 5.51.1

EDIT: FIXED

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fileLoader' of undefined
rsm_app-node-1 at Object.module.exports (/app/node_modules/file-loader/index.js:13:28)
```

Webpack.base.config:

```
module.exports = (opts) => {
// ...
    module: {
      rules: [
        { test: /\.jsx?$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules)/,
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              ['@babel/preset-env',
              {
                "targets": {
                  "esmodules": true
                }
              }]
            ],
            plugins: [
              '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
              '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime'
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: [
            {
              // Adds CSS to the DOM by injecting a `<style>` tag
              loader: 'style-loader'
            },
            {
              // Interprets `@import` and `url()` like `import/require()` and will resolve them
              loader: 'css-loader'
            },
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader'
            },
            {
              // Loader for webpack to process CSS with PostCSS
              loader: 'postcss-loader',
              options: {
                plugins: function () {
                  return [
                    require('autoprefixer')
                  ];
                }
              }
            },
            {
              // Loads a SASS/SCSS file and compiles it to CSS
              loader: 'sass-loader'
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/, 
          use: [
            'style-loader',
            'css-loader'
          ]
        },
        {test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/, loader: 'url-loader', options: {limit: 8192}},  // inline base64 URLs <=8k
        {test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|png)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: 'file-loader'},
      ], // add all common loaders here
    },

    resolve: {
      extensions: ['','.ts', '.js', '.jsx'],
      modules: [
        path.resolve(PROJECT_ROOT, 'rsm-app-react'),
        "node_modules",
      ],
    },
  };
};
```

Component:

```
import logo from '../data/logo.png';

return (
    <div className="ml-3 h-screen md:overflow-hidden overflow-auto md:hover:overflow-auto pb-10">
      {activeMenu && (
        <>
          <div className="flex justify-between items-center">
            <Link to="/" onClick={handleCloseSideBar} className="items-center gap-3 ml-3 mt-4 flex text-xl font-extrabold tracking-tight dark:text-white text-slate-900">
              { logo } <span class="company-name">Test</span>
            </Link>
```

Comment: Are you using Webpack 5? If so, consider using [asset modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/) instead

Comment: Why do you have two rules that would match `.png`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Webpack 5, I recommend you use [Asset Modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/) instead.

```js
// Webpack.base.config

module.exports = {
  // ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        type: "asset", // replaces url-loader, default limit is 8kb
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        type: "asset/resource", // replaces file-loader
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Your JSX should then `import` the images and use them in `<img>` tags

```jsx
import logo from "../data/logo.png";

// ...

<img src={logo} alt="Logo" />
```

Comment: I am using webpack 5.51.1, also I added more of the webpack code above.

Comment: @JabbatheHutt and? You didn't answer my question about the duplicate `.png` rules either

Comment: You mean for the url loader and file loader? Initially the url loader only had the png rule, I added it to the file-loader to test

Comment: It's best to avoid having multiple rules match the same thing. So did you try using the asset modules in my answer? Did it not work?

Comment: So I used the asset modules, and there is no error but instead of the image, I am getting "http://localhost:8080/bundles/" instead of the imported image

Comment: I might be importing the image wrong, I will post above what my component looks like

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

if you webpack version less then 5，you should try `yarn add -D file-loader` and webpack rules, and then input that code `import Img from 'xxx.jpg'` at entry file

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        use: {
        loader: 'file-loader',
      }
  }
]
```

}

Comment: My webpack version is 5.51.1

Comment: so, this operation is able